Magnetic field in different frames
If I move at the same velocity as that of a charge Q, I wouldn't be able to feel its magnetic field because it is stationary with respect to me.
However, if I am to place a magnetic compass needle stationary in between me and the charge, the needle will now deflect towards the charge, hence confirming that there is a magnetic field.
How does this work? If I am to consider me, the compass and the charge as one single system, what would be the final answer? Is there a magnetic field in this system, or is there not?
If I am to carry a compass with me while moving, will the needle on my compass deflect? If no, then is it not a paradox for the stationary needle to deflect and for mine to not? I'm clearly very new to this topic of relativity as a high school student so I would appreciate a little help.

If the compass is stationary with respect to the charge it should also not be able to detect a magnetic field as the component of the field strength it is measuring in a comoving frame will only contain electric contributions. I.e. I do not see a reason why the compass and I should be treated differently as observers in this setup. maybe I'm missing something obvious though so maybe you could explain why you would expect the compass to detect a magnetic field.

@ThomasTappeiner I used the 'compass with the observer' case only to show what I was confused about. It suggests that at a particular instant, my compass would imply that there is no magnetic field, yet the stationary compass implies the opposite. Isn't that a contradiction? Of course, there's not a significant difference between the observer and the compass.

A sorry misunderstood your setup. Yeah this is exactly what happens however there is no contradiction it just tells you that the magnetic field is not a well defined notion in relativity as it is not covariant. Rather one should look at the field strength which is covaraint. Then you directly see that what you call electric field and what you call magnetic field depends on the observer. So the comoving observer is actually expected to see something different.

Maybe a first glimps that this si the case can already be seen from magnetic force laws. Assume that the only interaction with the magnetic field is through the Lorenz force. Then the comoving observer has no way of ever measuring a magnetic field as the force is proportional to the relative velocity.

And moving magnets will produce electric fields. In general, the covariant quantity is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor

"If I move at the same velocity as that of a charge Q, I wouldn't be able to feel its magnetic field because it is stationary with respect to me." This is not true. If you Lorentz transformed to a frame where both are at rest, there would be no magnetic force. But in the frame you describe, where both are moving there will be a magnetic force.
